# Initialize an array in a structure

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'am writng a function that initialise an array inside a structure,
This is my structure :

```
struct NumArray {
int numSize;
int *nums;
};
```

the function am using to initialize a NumArray instance is as follow:

```
struct NumArray* NumArrayCreate(int* nums, int numsSize)
{
 struct NumArray* initStruct =(struct NumArray*)malloc(sizeof(struct NumArray));
 initStruct->nums =(int*)malloc (sizeof(int)*numsSize);

 initStruct->numSize = numsSize;
 memcpy (initStruct->nums, nums, numsSize);

 return initStruct;
}
```

Calling this function in the main gives me weird values:

```
int nums[5] = {9,2,3,4,5};
int main ()
{
 struct NumArray* numArray = NumArrayCreate(nums, 5);
 printf ("%i\n",numArray->nums[0]);
 printf ("%i\n",numArray->nums[1]);
 printf ("%i\n",numArray->nums[2]);
 printf ("%i\n",numArray->nums[3]);
}
```

using a 2nd version, i get the expected values, but i am wondering why the first version won't work, this is the 2nd version:

```
struct NumArray* NumArrayCreate(int* nums, int numsSize)
{
 struct NumArray* initStruct =(struct NumArray*)malloc(sizeof(struct NumArray));

 initStruct->numSize = numsSize;
 initStruct->nums = nums;

 return initStruct;
}
```

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not copying all the values. The second version works because the pointer is pointing the the array in `main()` so you are essentialy printing that array, i.e. `nums`.

To copy all the values, you need to use `numsSize` and multiply by the size of every element, note that `memcpy()` copies `numsSize` bytes. And you array is `numsSize * sizeof(initStruct->nums[0])` bytes in size so just change the `memcpy()` to

```
memcpy(initStruct->nums, nums, numsSize * sizeof(nums[0]));
```

Comment: Ahhhhh, Yes My Baaad

Comment: @fedi ALWAYS, check that `malloc()` didn't return `NULL` before using the pointer, and remove those ugly casts, they are not necessary.